# Grid accordion individual block resizing

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

Ive created a grid accordion, with an image and text in each block, but i cant seem to resize the block, the full content does not display, is there a way to size each individual block so when you click on the grid it expands to a bigger size so all content may be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines of this:

```
var myresizer = function(){
$('.mywhateverAccordion .mywhateverBlock').each(function(){
   var offset = 50;
   var whateverimage = $(this).children('img').get(0); 
   var whatevertext = $(this).children('.mywhatevertextclass').get(0); 
    var newheight = $(whateverimage).height() + $(whatevertext).height() + offset;
   $(this).height(newheight);
});
});

//Some ajax or whatever, changes, etc.
myresizer();
```